# What is the difference between `arr_2 = arr` and `arr_2 = arr.view()` and `arr_ 2 = arr.copy()`

Tags: python, numpy

The meaning of view and copy is different, if you have a view then if you change 1 the other should also change, if you have a copy then changing 1 should not affect the other
there are 3 ways of making a `view`/`copy` of an array

```py
arr_2 = arr
arr_2 = arr.view()
arr_2 = arr.copy()
```

all 3 of them seem to return a copy, I expected (view, view, copy)
Why is it so?

Edit: What I meant by `copy` is, changing either 1 of them **does not** change the other
and What I meant by `view` is, changing ether 1 of them changes the other

Comment: **No**. `arr_2 = arr` *does not make a copy*, nor does it make a view. That is simply assigning the exact same object to the name `arr_2`

Comment: Could you show us what makes you think `.view()` does not make a view?

Comment: "all 3 of them seem to return a copy, I expected (view, view, copy)" No. The first does *neither*, the second does a view, and the third is a copy. Both a copy and a view create *different objects*. A view *keeps the same underlying buffer*

Comment: Give an example of this 'seeming'.  How are you testing this?

Comment: I define `arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])` then I change `arr_2` to `arr_2 = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])` after that I `print(arr)` and it is unchanged

Comment: You assigned a whole new array to `arr_2`.  With that there's no longer any connection between `arr` and `arr_2`.  The correct way to test for `vew/copy`, is to do something like `arr_2[0] = 1000`, and see whether `arr` is changed.  This is an in-place change to `arr_2`, a `mutation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [488]: arr = np.array([1,2,3,4])
In [489]: arr2 = arr
```

changing an element of `arr2` changes `arr` as well, because the variables reference the same array:

```
In [490]: arr2[0]=100
In [491]: arr
Out[491]: array([100,   2,   3,   4])
```

Doing `arr2=np.array([3,4])` assigns a whole new array to `arr2`, and removes any connection they had via [489].  This is not a useful test for view/copy.

Making a `view`:

```
In [492]: arr2 = arr.reshape(2,2)
In [493]: arr2
Out[493]: 
array([[100,   2],
       [  3,   4]])
In [494]: arr2[0,0] = 200
In [495]: arr
Out[495]: array([200,   2,   3,   4])
```

`arr2` has a different shape, but it still shares the data-buffer with `arr`.  I didn't use `arr.view()` because that's rarely used; it doesn't do anything significant.  Read the `view` docs to see why.

A copy makes a new array with its own data-buffer:

```
In [496]: arr2 = arr.copy()
In [497]: arr2[0] = 50
In [498]: arr2
Out[498]: array([50,  2,  3,  4])
In [499]: arr
Out[499]: array([200,   2,   3,   4])
```

`arr2=np.array(arr)` will also make a copy.  Compare its docs and `np.asarray`.

Answer (score 1):

**Three ways of copying array in python**

- *Assigning Operator* (=): It only creates a new variable that shares the reference of the original object
- *Shallow Copy* (.view()): A reference of the object is copied in another object. It means that any changes made to a copy of the object do reflect in the original object.
- *Deep Copy* (.copy()): A copy of the object is copied into another object. It means that any changes made to a copy of the object do not reflect in the original object.

Comment: A view is a new array object, but it shares the data buffer.  A copy has its own data.  But if dtype is object, there is another `deep_copy` option (as with lists).

Comment: `np.copy` actually does `np.array(a, order=order, subok=subok, copy=True)`.  Read the docs for the `copy` method and the function.

Comment: See the OP's comment describing how he's "testing" for change.